# efficient way to do a reverse wildcard in a mysql query?

Tags: mysql, pattern-matching

I'm writing a Drupal module, but this question is not Drupal-specific.

Drupal has a table called `menu_router`, where it associates human-friendly URLs to the actual url that can pull up content. For example:

```
+--------------------------------------------------------+
| admin/config/media/image-styles/edit/%/add/%           |
| admin/config/media/image-styles/edit/%/effects/%       |
| admin/structure/types/manage/%/comment/fields/%/delete |
| admin/structure/types/manage/%/comment/fields/%/edit   |
+--------------------------------------------------------+
```

I have a arbitrary url and I want to make sure that it actually maps to a valid url on the site. However I can't easily do a wildcard query, because as you can see above, the wildcarded string already exists as the column value, and my search criteria would be the match!

So for instance, `'arbitrary/url/string/'` would match `'arbitary/%/string'`, according to the way Drupal handles URLs.

What's an efficient way I can query to see if any given string matches any of the wildcarded Drupal-style urls?

Comment: I don't believe that there's a "master"-regexp that will match all the strings you're looking for. You'll probably have to create a different regexp for each string!

Answer (score 0):

I suppose you could make one big pattern out of the lines of menu_router (i.e. an OR of the pattern for each line), and then see if your target gets matched.  So long as you don't need to know which of the lines in menu_router it matches, that is.